# Reading information from nmap poodle vulnerability result. Bash script

Tags: bash, ssl, nmap

I need to make a bash script that will give me a list of true or false  depending on the address it scanned.
Right now I have this simple script

```
#!/bin/bash
input="/root/file1"
input2="/root/file2"
paste -d, file{1,2}.txt | while IFS=, read x y; 
do   nmap -sV --version-light --script ssl-poodle -p $y $x
if something(detects its vulnerable)
echo "true">>file3.txt
else (not vulnerable)
echo "false">>fie3.txt
done
```

the information nmap returns when vulerable is

Nmap scan report for ip
Host is up (0.044s latency).
PORT    STATE SERVICE  VERSION
port/tcp open  ssl/http Microsoft IIS
| ssl-poodle: 
|   VULNERABLE:
|   SSL POODLE information leak
|     State: VULNERABLE

Is there a way to detect the word vulnerable, or what would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
input="/root/file1"
input2="/root/file2"
paste -d, file{1,2}.txt | while IFS=, read x y; 
do
    nmap_output="$(nmap -sV --version-light --script ssl-poodle -p $y $x)"
    if [ -n "$(echo "$nmap_output" | grep VULNERABLE)" ]
    echo "true">>file3.txt
    else
    echo "false">>fie3.txt
done
```

### Explanation

With this line

```
nmap_output="$(nmap -sV --version-light --script ssl-poodle -p $y $x)"
```

you are saving the output of `nmap` execution to the `$nmap_output` variable.

And, with this one:

```
if [ -n "$(echo "$nmap_output" | grep VULNERABLE)" ]
```

you are checking if the nmap output contains the word VULNREABLE. It does so by grepping the nmap output and keeping only lines with the VULNERABLE word. Then, it checks if the grepped string is not empty (the `-n` switch at the beggining of the `if`).